# SQL Service keeps falling over

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, diagnostic

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter running SQL Server 2016 (SP1) 
The SQL Service fails randomly with the following error in the Logs :-

Computer type is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz.
Bios Version is VRTUAL - 5001223
BIOS Date: 05/23/12 17:15:53  Ver: 09.00.06
8 X64 level 8664, 10 Mhz processor (s).
Windows NT 6.2 Build 9200 CSD .

Memory
MemoryLoad = 96%
Total Physical = 57343 MB
Available Physical = 2083 MB
Total Page File = 124739 MB
Available Page File = 12848 MB
Total Virtual = 134217727 MB
Available Virtual = 134130206 MB
***Unable to get thread context for spid 0

---

- - BEGIN STACK DUMP:
- 12/07/17 19:08:33 spid 119916
- - Non-yielding Scheduler
- ---

I've been asked to diagnose this issue but my SQL knowledge is limited. 
We have captured a mini dump file which I ran through the SQL Diagnostics tool here :-

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview/

It didn't find anything so I'm hoping you guys can point me in the right direction

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. If you need further information, please ask 
Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Make sure that you are fully patched and have verified backups. Then open a ticket with Microsoft. Non-yielding Scheduler issues typically require Microsoft's help to resolve.

Comment: John, Thanks we have raised this with the MS Partner Forum who are providing assistance. We have identified a patch that we think directly addresses this issue. The link is below in case it helps anyone else :-

FIX: "Non-yielding Scheduler" condition occurs on spinlock contention in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 or 2016
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4024311/fix-non-yielding-scheduler-condition-occurs-on-spinlock-contention-in